# faq toggle adding selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have toggle faq.

When I click on " + " it toogle answer and show/hide it.

I want to make toggle if I click on " + " and also on title of question.

### Question:

How to toggle answer with **`h3`** element (title of question) **and/or** **+** **button**?

### HTML:

```
<div class="box boxFaq clearfix">                  
    <div class="boxTitle">
        <h3>Question</h3>
    </div>
    <button class="clearfix">+</button>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="boxContent clearfix toggle">                     
        Answer answer answer                                                                    
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('button').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).next().next('.toggle').slideToggle();
        if (jQuery(this).text() === '+') {
            jQuery(this).html('-');
        }
        else {
            jQuery(this).html('+');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a self-answered question? In that case, you should post your answer as an actual answer, not in the question itself.

Comment: `jQuery(this).next().next('.toggle')` is not really maintanable, `jQuery(this).closest('.box').find('.toggle')` looks better IMO

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I am not self answering my own question. Trying to find solution to it, and adjust specific solution to example I posted.

Comment: @A.Wolff I know this method, but my goal was to not target selector as $this in jquery, the reason is that then I change content of both selectors, I need to change content only of button */-.

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak i don't understand what you are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include multiple selectors by separating them with a `,`. Then you just need to slightly amend the logic of the handler to work for both elements. Try this:

```
jQuery('.boxFaq button, .boxFaq h3').click(function() {
    var $parent = jQuery(this).closest('.boxFaq');
    var $btn = $parent.find('button')
    $parent.find('.toggle').slideToggle();
    $btn.text($btn.text() === '+' ? '-' : '+');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MYA4Y/1)

Note also I amended the `+/-` logic to a simple ternary expression.

Comment: If I toogle, then my H3 element have +/- content. I want Question untouched. Don't change content of H3 element.

Comment: If I click on Question, then button have still "+" content. When I toggle , content of button should change to "-" .

Comment: You're correct, I misread the structure. Try the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

add h3 to selector..and use `parents()` or `closest()`

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('h3,button').click(function() {
     var $parent=jQuery(this).parents('.boxFaq');
    $parent.find('.toggle').slideToggle();
    if ($parent.find('button').text() === '+') {
        jQuery(this).html('-');
    }
    else{
        jQuery(this).html('+');
    }

   });
 });
```

Comment: you are changing also H3 element content to +/-. Question (h3) must not change. I change only + / - in button. Question and Answer should not be edited

Comment: parents should work... did u try replacing it with closest ??

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (jQuery(this).text() === '+') {
            $('h3').text('Answer');  //Change the text here
            jQuery(this).html('-');  
        }
        else {
            jQuery(this).html('+');
            $('h3').text('Question');  //Again here
        }
```

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/frpKr/5/)

Comment: I change only + / - in button. Question and Answer should not be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Modify you HTML code

```
<div class="boxContent clearfix toggle" style="display: none;">                     
        Answer answer answer                                                                    
    </div>
```

Modify you jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('button').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).next().next().slideToggle();
        if (jQuery(this).text() === '+') {
            jQuery(this).html('-');
        }
        else {
            jQuery(this).html('+');
        }
    });
});
```

Check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekx2H/)